# How can I run foreach loop into filtered row in Ultra Grid?

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

How I can run for loop only filtered rows into UltraGrid?
Suppose I've a Ultra grid about 1000 rows. But I need only run loop for 5 rows which I shall get by filtering

```
foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdMerchandiserToBuyer.Rows)
{
}
```

This code fetch all rows, but I want only filtered Rows into this Grid

Please help me if anyone know that
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `UltraGrid.Rows` property is of type `RowsCollection`, which has a method `GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows`. You should be able to do something like this:

```
foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdMerchaniserToBuyer.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows())
{
   // your code here
}
```

[https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.rowscollection~getfilteredinnongroupbyrows](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.rowscollection%7Egetfilteredinnongroupbyrows)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 5 filtered rows, but it's required to get only first five:

```cs
foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdMerchandiserToBuyer.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows().Take(5))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I need x no of rows that may be 5 or 25 or 430, or 200

Comment: @FarabiShohan: In your question you wrote: **"I need only run loop for 5 rows"**. Update your question to describe what you want to achieve clearly.